# Should a string with only spaces be considered 'empty' in Python (validation purposes)

Tags: python, string, validation, spaces

I am currently updating an input validation library from a year ago, and while reviewing the IsEmpty() validator, I noticed that it was seeing strings with only spaces as NOT EMPTY, like so:

```
s = ' '
```

This is of course normal, as Python sees strings with spaces as containing value as opposed to  a truly empty string that would evaluate to None.

My question is, can anyone think of a reason why I should not make a string with spaces evaluate to EMPTY for the purposes of my validation library?

Thoughts appreciated.

EDIT: I am updating this to clarify that this question was NOT INTENDED to cover a domain specific application. This library is open source and I am updating for the benefit of the community. Therefore, this question was more of a survey to hear out suggestions on how to implement this (in the manner of a library) to best serve Python developers and their validation needs. I have opted to include 2 methods to provide flexibility to consuming programs.

Comment: Depends on whether the code that consumes the strings will make such a distinction, or not.

Comment: In most cases, if you want the user to fill a field in a form (eg: name or email), it shouldn't be empty and empty spaces may be removed, so the string will be considered as empty. Can you describe the goal/use of your validation library?

Comment: just use `myinput.strip()` if you want spaces to be empty

Comment: This is an odd question because it's a question only you can answer.  You know the needs of your application, we don't.  Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: A "truly empty string" doesn't evaluate to `None`, it evaluates to `''`

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher sorry for not being precise

For those who voted to close question, the reason I posted it was because this is for a general purpose library that is open source and intended to be used by the Python community at large. I have no specific use case in mind for this question, I wanted to see people's thoughts since it is intended for anybody's use, across all domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a domain-dependant question - it depends on each application.

I would suggest having two functions, one which defaults one way, and the other which defaults the other, and each having a keyword argument to select the other behaviour.

Comment: I would just have the first sentence ... since its domain specific you would probably not want it both ways but one or the other so just choose appropriately (+1 all the same)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I would have two methods because it's domain specific - that way, the programmer can choose whichever represents their normal case, and then alter it as necessary using a switch.

Comment: Agree with this approach.

The reason I posted the question was not because I was looking for a domain specific answer since the library I am updating is open source and I intend it to be useful to many people as a gen-purp library. Having 2 separate functions is the most flexible approach suggested and so I am accepting this solution. The library I am updating is Konval (https://github.com/agapow/Py-konval) I will merge in my (now significant) updates in a few days. Thanks for all input!

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone think of a reason why I should not make a string with spaces evaluate to EMPTY for the purposes of my validation library?

You need a reason TO do something before a reason NOT to do it is relevant.

It doesn't make any sense to just arbitrarily perform an operation like space-trimming unless you have a reason to.

Extra operations ~= extra lines of code ~= extra CPU time, etc.

Comment: Agreed. I can think of several reasons to make empty strings validate to empty. One that comes to mind is that it saves the client programmer the trouble of space trimming. On the other hand, you may want to allow a string with only spaces through a validator and let the database code decide later how to deal with that value.